# R 3d plot error with intersecting planes

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot, scatter3d

This has stumped me all day long.  Can anyone help me to understand why my data is providing me these plots, which contain intersecting planes alongside of my 3D-scatterplot?  The planes occur using all 3 of the methods below.

There may be an issue in my use of unlist of the matrix that created the attached dataset.

Link
[Source Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1niEoJd3CgRdIjgWJmQqqMA23oqmSrWQneKCmepcadJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

```
open3d()
bg3d(color="white")
points3d(freq_subdata$x_ft,freq_subdata$y_ft,freq_subdata$count)

plot3d(freq_subdata$x_ft,freq_subdata$y_ft,freq_subdata$count)

rgl.open()
rgl.bg(color="white")
rgl.points(freq_subdata$x_ft,freq_subdata$y_ft,freq_subdata$count,color="black")
```

[image: 3D Planes on Scatterplot]

```
> dput(head(freq_subdata,20))
structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), y = 1:20, x_ft = c(2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), y_ft = c(2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 
22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5, 
77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 92.5, 97.5), count = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 
12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 
38L, 40L), proportion = c(6.18888476296571e-05, 0.000123777695259314, 
0.000185666542888971, 0.000247555390518629, 0.000309444238148286, 
0.000371333085777943, 0.0004332219334076, 0.000495110781037257, 
0.000556999628666914, 0.000618888476296571, 0.000680777323926229, 
0.000742666171555886, 0.000804555019185543, 0.0008664438668152, 
0.000928332714444857, 0.000990221562074514, 0.00105211040970417, 
0.00111399925733383, 0.00117588810496349, 0.00123777695259314
)), .Names = c("x", "y", "x_ft", "y_ft", "count", "proportion"
), row.names = c("Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14", "Var15", 
"Var16", "Var17", "Var18", "Var19", "Var110", "Var111", "Var112", 
"Var113", "Var114", "Var115", "Var116", "Var117", "Var118", "Var119", 
"Var120"), class = "data.frame")
```

Link
[Source Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1niEoJd3CgRdIjgWJmQqqMA23oqmSrWQneKCmepcadJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(freq_subdata, 20))`   Just paste the results into your question.